# Delete child objects when removed from parent collection

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, jpa-2.0

I am currently experiencing a problem that is very similar to the one discussed here 
[Hibernate triggering constraint violations using orphanRemoval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068817/hibernate-triggering-constraint-violations-using-orphanremoval)

Unfortunately I get a **SqlException - Column cannot be null** error. My entities are as follows:

**CallDetail**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "callDetail", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<CallCycleDetail> callCycles;

public void addCallCycleDetail(CallCycleDetail callCycleDetail) {
    if (this.callCycles == null) {
        this.callCycles = new HashSet<CallCycleDetail>();
    }
  callCycles.add(callCycleDetail);
  callCycleDetail.setCallDetail(this);
}

public void removeCallCycleDetail(CallCycleDetail callCycleDetail) {
  callCycles.remove(callCycleDetail);
  callCycleDetail.setCallDetail(null);
}
```

**CallCycleDetail**

```
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "call_detail", nullable=false)
private CallDetail callDetail;
```

My JUnit test is as follows:

```
CallDetail callDetail = createCallDetail();
CallCycleDetail ccd = new CallCycleDetail(callDetail);
callDetail.addCallCycleDetail(ccd);
callDetailService.saveCallDetail(callDetail);

callDetail = callDetailService.findCallDetail(callDetail.getId());
callDetail.removeCallCycleDetail(ccd);
callDetailService.updateCallDetail(callDetail);
```

It saves correctly. However when I try to clear the set of callCycles, it fails with the Notnull constraint. How can I fix this?

Comment: Even if it hurts, one solution is to remove the `nullable=false` of the CallDetail. I encountered this problem once, and it seems, Hibernate first sets the forign key field to null, and wants to delete these orphans later on.

Comment: @UweAllner Thank you for the response. I have removed `@JoinColumn(name = "call_detail", nullable=false)`. However the exception is still thrown.

Comment: Hopefully not the whole annotiation? Only the nullable attribute... And I think, you will not need to do `callCycleDetail.setCallDetail(null);`; Hibernate will recognize that the CallDetail has been removed from the collection.

Comment: @UweAllner I also had to remove the `(optional=false)` part of the annotation for this to work. It seems like this is indeed a Hibernate error as described in [HHH-6709](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6709). Thank You.

Comment: What is the vendor of your database ?