# Spring Framework + Spring Data + Hibernate Jpa OneToMany child removal fails

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have an unidirectional OneToMany JPA entity mapping in my (Spring Framework + Spring Data + Hibernate JPA) project. Entity classes are like in the following code.(I have removed irrelevant class members for brevity).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
class Employee{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Integer id;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
   private List<DepartmentAssignment> departmentAssignments = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "department_assignments")
class DepartmentAssignment{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Integer id;

   @NotNull
   @Column(name = "employee_id")
   private Integer employeeId;

   @NotNull
   @Column(name = "department_id")
   private Integer departmentId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "departments")
class Department{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Integer id;       
}
```

And, in one of my service classes have a method to remove a DepartmentAssignment from an Employee like below.

```
public Employee deleteDepartmentAssignment(Integer empId, Integer deptAssignmentId) {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findOne(empId);
        if(employee != null) {
            for ( DepartmentAssignment da : employee.getDepartmentAssignments()) {
                if(da.getId().equals(deptAssignmentId)) {
                    employee.getDepartmentAssignments().remove(da);
                    employee = employeeRepository.save(employee);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return employee;
    }
```

However, calling above methods gives me an error: `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` ,and in the SQL log, I can see `Column 'employee_id' cannot be null` error for the last SQL statement of the transaction.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here and how to get it fixed?

Comment: Please, add full stack trace.

Comment: Is there anything else in the DepartmentAssignment class? If not whats the point of it. You could remove it without any functional loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "employee_id")
private Integer employeeId;
```

to the `Employee`, if you use `@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")`. Try to remove it.

Comment: Trying your suggestion gives me the following error and it fails to load the spring context too. ` org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException:  Table [departments_assignments] contains physical column name [employee_id] represented by different logical column names: [employeeId], [employee_id] `

Comment: @Tharanga You should remove all `employeeId` and `employee_id` from `DepartmentAssignment` and update a schema.

Comment: I want to thank you. Removing employeeId altogether worked like a charm.

Comment: @Tharanga You are welcome. Thanks for up vote.  `private Integer departmentId;` looks strange too. Please, never use such associations. You  should to  use associations to objects (using lazy, for an example).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following, not sure why you use the plain id in the object. Thats not object relational mapping. 
For more details see  [Hibernate triggering constraint violations using orphanRemoval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068817/hibernate-triggering-constraint-violations-using-orphanremoval)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
class Employee{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee", orphanRemoval = true)
   private List<DepartmentAssignment> departmentAssignments = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "department_assignments")
class DepartmentAssignment{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;

   @ManyToOne(optional=false)
   private Employee employee;

   @ManyToOne(optional=false)
   private Department department;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "departments")
class Department{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;       
}
```

Comment: Thank you for coming to help me. The reason I didn't make it bidirectional is that, according to my business model, it is not intended to access Employee from DepartmentAssignment.  Your suggestion to make it bidirectional should work. I removed employeeId altogether from  DepartmentAssignment entity, and it works as intended now.

Answer (score 0):

You must look **.hbm.xml** file and you should mapping your Entity in this file and 
you can look this example

> http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/

I hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: It is not useful. Because of he uses mapping by annotations, not xm-mapping.

Comment: I'm not using a .hbm file. Its all annotation based mapping with hibernate-jpa.

Answer (score -1):

try removing

```
cascade = CascadeType.ALL
```

but im not 100% sure..

Comment: did u try it? , i this it is the reason

Comment: It is impossible to update children via a parent  with default `cascading`.

Comment: Then add relevant cascade types not All. Like CascadeType.Merge

Comment: It is possible. But, I think, the reason of an issue is not `cascade`.

Comment: Hmm ok but CascadeType.All means that any change to the parent object will mark the child objects for update